# Styles for Google TV and Honeycomb Tablets

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, google-tv

I want my application to run on tablets and Google TV.  I have made my layouts, pertaining to positioning, all depend on weights to handle scaling appropriately.  My intent now is to place my text styles (size, color, etc...) in style sheets.  Will Google TV only grab from either the values-large-tvdpi or the values-large-xhdpi folders?  Will HoneyComb tablets grab from values-large-mdpi and values-large-hdpi folders? Is there situations where the tablet and tv will conflict with grabbing from the same folder?

Answer (score 1):

If you add -notouch or -finger (or -stylus) resource qualifiers to differentiate.  -notouch is for TV, -finger for a touch screen.